# Angular.js web page routing not working for SPA (using ng-view and routeProvider)

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ng-view, route-provider

I am trying to insert a view in my index.html using $routeProvider and ng-view from Angularjs libraries.  Can anyone help figure out why it is not getting inserted?

Here are my index.html, my views, and my app.js files:

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en' ng-app="myApp">
<head>


   <script src="app/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="app/lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
   <script src="app/lib/app.js"></script>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>

<main ng-view>
</main>

</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){

$routeProvider

  .when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'views/login.html'
  })

  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/login'
  });

}]);
```

my login.html (which is in the views folder of my project):

```
<h1>Welcome to the login page!</h1>
```

When I try and preview this page in atom the index.html is empty.  Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: sorry ... what is main ?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully You're running your application on some server.Because the same code is working fine for me.

app.js file

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider
    .when('/login', {
      template: '<h1>Welcome to the login page!</h1>'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/login'
    });

}]);
```

Click [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/TdlGm39KBWadTETozNYz?p=preview) for working plunker.

Comment: Yea it looked like a problem with the preview in atom thank you!